# Changing the colour of the root with Tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, darkmode

I have implemented dark mode into my application however it doesn't seem to affect the root as it's still white even when dark mode is `true`.
I have been searching for days to find a solution but I'm unable to come across one.

I have produced a MRE (bar logic for one function) of my application here. Apologies if it is long however I was not sure how much to include

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css'
import App from './App';
import { ContextProvider } from './context/ContextProvider';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <ContextProvider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ContextProvider>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useStateContext } from './context/ContextProvider';

function App() {

  const { darkMode } = useStateContext()

  return (
    <div className={`${darkMode === true ? 'dark' : ''}`}>
      <div className='dark:bg-dark-grey min-h-screen'>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/home/' element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

ContextProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const StateContext = createContext();

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const getInitialTheme = () => {
        ...
    }

    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(getInitialTheme())

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider
            value={{
                darkMode,
                setDarkMode,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    ],
    darkMode: 'class',
    theme: {
         ...
    }
}
```

This is how the page looks when I scroll down from the top of the page, how can I get the white background to disappear?
[image: root showing white]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind uses [**prefers-color-scheme**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) feature by default, that means it will ignore your custom class, if you want toggle light/dark mode manually by class, you have to edit `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
}
```

More info: [Tailwind CSS Dark Mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have that in my config already and have added it to the original question for clarity

Comment: Oh, have you then checked value of darkMode that you are storing in Context? Looks like problem could be there, I would start in App.js, check what darkMode value is, it could be also problem with `getInitialTheme()`

Comment: The value is stored in context as a boolean. `getInitialTheme()` is only used to check if the user has dark mode enabled on their machine on render. The result is the same with and without `getInitialTheme()`. It seems like dark mode is being applied to the body but not the root

Comment: Oh, hope I get it now, sorry, it was quite confusing for me, thought it doesn't register dark mode right, well, I would suggest you set `margin: 0; padding: 0;` and make the App Component use whole screen (`width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`)